# What's the difference between %ul and %lu C format specifiers?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

In an example of "C Primer Plus", the author has used `%ul` format specifier (in both scanf and printf) for **unsigned long**. When I try to generalize the problem, it seems that the `%ul` makes something wrong in my computer. But using `%lu` solved the issue.

Actually, rather than focusing on the problem and the line of codes, I want to know about the difference between `%ul` and `%lu`. Maybe I could figure out what's wrong.

Searching doesn't give me something useful (except that "they are different").

Any explanation or link/reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`%lu` is correct, while `%ul` is *incorrect*.

A [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) format specifier follows the form `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`.

`u` is a *specifier* meaning "unsigned decimal integer".

`l` is a *length* modifier meaning "long".

The *length* modifier should go before the conversion *specifier*, which means `%lu` is correct.

Comment: `%ul` is correct but won't work as the OP is expected. It'll print out the number with suffix `l` at the end because it's just `%u`, `l` is outside the format