# Unintended unsigned max result

Tags: c, types, range, unsigned, format-specifiers

I am attempting to do exercise 2-1 of K&R C but when I run the program, the result is this:

```
        UNSIGNED TYPES
UNSIGNED CHAR:  0     255
UNSIGNED SHORT: 0     65535
UNSIGNED INT:   0     -1
UNSIGNED LONG;  0     -1
```

The result of `UNSIGNED INT` and `UNSIGNED LONG` weren't supposed to be `-1`, it was supposed to be the value in the reference. (Appendix B.11 Page 213)

```
/* UNSIGNED TYPES */
printf("\n\tUNSIGNED TYPES\n");
printf("UNSIGNED CHAR:  %d      %d\n", 0, UCHAR_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED SHORT: %d      %d\n", 0, USHRT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED INT:   %d      %d\n", 0, UINT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED LONG:  %d      %d\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
```

The strange part is that I don't think there's something wrong with my code, the minimum range is `0` because I read that `unsigned` types are non-negative. I already included `limits.h` and `float.h`.

How do I solve this problem?

The link of the full program is [here](https://gist.github.com/alexanderfalgui/9d818dc7f80ceac55a08).

**UPDATE 1:** I tried replacing `%d` of the max range for `unsigned long` and that seemed to work but the `unsigned int` is `4294967925` instead of `65535`. Thanks for helping me fix the `unsigned long` problem and I hope you guys can help me with the `unsigned int` issue.

**UPDATE 2:** I changed the `ULONG_MAX`'s character sequence from `%ul` to `%lu`.

Here's the code and the result:

**Code:**

```
/* UNSIGNED TYPES */
printf("\n\tUNSIGNED TYPES\n");
printf("UNSIGNED CHAR:  %d      %u\n", 0, UCHAR_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED SHORT: %d      %u\n", 0, USHRT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED INT:   %d      %u\n", 0, UINT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED LONG:  %d      %lu\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
```

**Result:**

```
        UNSIGNED TYPES
UNSIGNED CHAR:  0     255
UNSIGNED SHORT: 0     65535
UNSIGNED INT:   0     4294967925
UNSIGNED LONG;  0     4294967925
```

Comment: `%ul` should be `%lu`, and you mis-transcribed `l` as `1` in the last line of the result

Comment: I did that already and it seemed to work much better than `%ul` but would you care to explain (if you know) why `%ul` adds one at the end of `ULONG_MAX`? and why `%lu` doesn't?

Comment: `%ul` is `%u` followed by the letter `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` is for signed integers, for unsigned int and long use `%u` and `%lu` respectively.

Comment: It worked for `unsigned long` (`ULONG_MAX`) but the shouldn't `UINT_MAX` be `65535` instead of `4294967925`?

Comment: I don't think `%ul` is POSIX. You should use `%lu` instead.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Ok, that made `ULONG_MAX` better but what about `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: @AlexanderB.Falgui For that you just need plain `%u`.

Comment: @AlexanderB.Falgui, on 64-bit machines `int` is also 4-bytes long.

Comment: @Potatoswatter how do I make `%ju` work? the `PRIuMAX` macro from `<inttypes.h>` print `4924261` instead of `65535`...

Comment: @AlexanderB.Falgui Sorry, I misread the question. `%ju` is for another type entirely, `uintmax_t` which is usually `unsigned long long`. Comment edited; you only need plain `%u`.

Comment: it's [`%lu`, not `%ul`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852073/whats-the-difference-between-ul-and-lu-c-format-specifiers/23852134?noredirect=1#comment36708180_23852134).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a format spec of `%u` to print an unsigned int.

By using `%d`, the bit pattern is interpreted as a signed int.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy exactly the output of the program? You write `UNSIGNED LONG:` in the code but then in the output it becomes `UNSIGNED LONG;`. There's no way `unsigned long` is one digit longer than `unsigned int`

Also, you're using the *wrong type specifier* and that results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714). You must use `%u` for `unsigned int`, with `l` length modifier for `long`, `ll` for `long long`.

The era of 16-bit computing has long gone decades ago, so `int`'s size is 32 bits on most modern systems except some 8 or 16-bit embedded systems, hence the range is [0, 2<sup>32</sup>-1] or [0, 4294967295] as you see. Depends on systems you're using, `long` will have different sizes. Typically on Windows it's a 32-bit type and on Unix/Linux it's 64 bits. C standard requires `int` to be at least 16 bits, `long` to be at least 32 bits. Only `long long` are guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, so you need to check for it as well.

```
printf("UNSIGNED CHAR:       %u    %u\n",   0U, UCHAR_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED SHORT:      %u    %u\n",   0U, USHORT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED INT:        %u    %u\n",   0U, UINT_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED LONG:       %lu   %lu\n",  0UL, ULONG_MAX);
printf("UNSIGNED LONG LONG:  %llu  %llu\n", 0ULL, ULONGLONG_MAX);
```

If you're on Windows, both unsigned int and unsigned long's max should be 4294967295.

Note that using ALL CAPS is a very bad choice

Comment: I`d +1 your answer since it gave me more information about 16, 32, and 64 bits but I lack reputation to do so. I'll do that if I can.